# Some bucket files are either completely private or completely public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

What I want to happen is I want my bucket available only from "thesite.com" or "thesite2.com". This setting works for most of the files in the bucket.

I've cross checked the files to see if there's anything different about it vs the files that are working and I couldn't find any difference that stood out.

Here's my bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.thesite.com and thesite.com.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::the-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://www.thesite.com/*",
                        "https://thesite.com/*",
                        "https://www.thesite2.com/*",
                        "https://thesite2.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my Cors Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.thesite.com/</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.thesite2.com/</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

So the problem is that some files seem to be not registering those changes. I had to set those files as "public" and that's not what I want to do, because now it's available to everyone and not just my users.
Could anybody offer any troubleshooting tips I can run through to help fix this problem? These are huge files so re-uploading them should be the very last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after digging around for a while. 
I realized that it was a permission problem. Me as a different user than the other user that uploaded the file, I guess it restricted any change to it?

So in addition to what I already have in the bucket policy, I added this:

```
        {
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
```

Now the files picked up the Cors Configuration. phew*